# Firestore / Cloud functions - Race Condition

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I use an Android App to store data in firestore. I have several batched writes that either add, delete or update documents.

I created a test within the App that invokes the following actions:

15 add, 65 update, 15 delete

Each of these actions will trigger a cloud function via onCreate(), onUpdate() and onDelete()

On the frontend I test this in two ways:

1. I execute one set of batch writes (max. 4 set,delete,update at once), wait for the backend functions results to be present in my app and after I execute the next set of batched writes. The batched writes never write to the same document of course.
2. I execute all set of batched writes (in the same order as before) but without any delay so all batched writes will hit the server at the "same time" (or at least the firebase library/database on my phone - persistence is enabled). The Cloud function trigger are expected to trigger somewhen after - in any imagineable order.

The cloud functions can deal with this. The update function can deal with being called without add being called before etc..So the order of invokation on my functions does not matter. But what matters is that I do not have the same calls to the same functions.

For case 1:
If I search the cloud logs I will find exactly this number and everything works as planned

15 onCreate, 65 onUpdate, 15 onDelete are present -> Total 95

For case 2:
If everything hits the server at the same time. I see those numbers in the log
(This is already cleaned of all duplicates due to retrys / contention)

6 onCreate, 74 onUpdate, 7 onDelete are present -> Total 87

Of course the expected result now also differs, because the functions are not called the correct number of times

Why do I experience this behavior? Is the frontend combining multiple batched writes that occur really close after each other on the same document into one change before sending it to the server?

(Persistence is enabled). Right now, I don't know how to deal with the race condition.

Another way to think about this:
What happens without network connection if multiple batched writes are commited locally.

I expect all those write to hit the server as if they would if connection is there. If they are bundled before, I have a problem because I rely on the cloud function to trigger